# More Scripting using .vbs and .bat

Tags: vbscript, scripting

Thanks again in advance for the help.
I made another post about scripting but due to them being different questions, I didn't want to combine them.

So I want to make an Autorun.inf file that runs when I connect my USB.
The USB will start in a "readonly" state.
My Scripts will be on the USB and basically will run a command to clear the attribute of readonly using diskpart, which will then find a specified path.
It will then copy all contents of the specified path onto the USB.
Once completed it will run diskpart in order to set the attribute to readonly one again.
And then finally, it will set the reg key for USB Autoplay disabled so no other USB's can connect to the machine.

I have scripted everything, it all works... But I want to know if I can combine them using VBS or even a Normal Batch into 1 file.

My scripts are as follows.

```
@echo    
diskpart.exe /s C:\Users\Jarryd\Desktop\clear.txt    
set source=C:\Users\Jarryd\Desktop\Backup\IRIS     
set destination=E:\IRIS   
xcopy %source% %destination% /y    
timeout 5
set source=C:\Users\Jarryd\Desktop\Backup\Face     
set destination=E:\Face   
xcopy %source% %destination% /y
diskpart.exe /s c:\Users\Jarryd\Desktop\set.txt
pause
```

The 2 text files that give the diskpart.exe commands

clear attribute

```
Select Disk 1
attributes disk clear readonly
```

set attribute

```
Select Disk 1
attributes disk clear readonly
```

and then finally the script to disable AutoPlay of USB's

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR]
"Start" = dword:00000004
```

I use a vbs script to run the reg key script so that it is hidden.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "regedit /s C:\Users\John\Desktop\ClosePorts.reg" ,1 ,True
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

So yeah basically all of that into 1 vbs script or any script would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: OK and what is the problem you are stuck with? To answer your question, yes, doing these things with VBScript is certainly possible. Have you tried? If yes, where are you stuck? If no, why not?

Comment: I just do not know how to convert the script to the VBScript language. This is what I am stuck with. As you can see I just use the VBScript to run my files as that is a simple task. I have no idea how to put them all into one. 
On a side not I see AUTORUN.INF does not work in win 7 & 8

Comment: If you have no idea about VBScript and you have a working batch script version, why switch? (The *"this won't work in modern versions of Windows anyway"* issue is the next thing I was going to mention...)

Comment: I just thought it would be more practical if I did it with one script instead of multiple.
But I do see your point...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, by all means learn how to do it with VBScript, one sub-task at a time. Copying a file, starting a process, setting a registry key, all those things are possible. There is a ton of tutorials and examples on how to do each of these things in VBS. But putting up a bunch of BAT code on StackOverflow along with a "please translate this to VBS for me" is not how this website works. :) Make an effort, spend a day reading and trying and come back with specific questions. (That the solution you aim for might not work with Win8 is a different matter entirely, though.)

Comment: I understand, my apologies. 
But thank you for the assistance.
Ill will go and read up on some more tutorials and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

I found a script that would do this and tried modifying it the way I need it, but it is too advanced for me and honestly too difficult so I am going to go with the suggest from @Tomalak and just stick to the batch file script.

Thanks

Comment: This ain't an answer to the question, it should probably go in to the comments